# Prevent Spam on RESTful JSON Webservice

Tags: web-services, security, rest

I have a webservice implemented in grails to deal with POSTs from a GWT client. If the user logges in he also could access as well the webservice without GWT just over the browser.

My question is now how can I secure it in a way that its not possible to spam my webservice with e.g. 1000 new entries just by stress my webservice with a specific posts(maybe over a loop) when logged in?

Same is also for Android clients or if I grant other developers to my webservice and they could POST thousands of data into my webservice.

Is there already a mechanism I can use?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users of this REST api need to be tied to an API key.   A [cryptographic nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) is usually the tool of choice.  In order to be issued this key the user should be required to solve a captcha.   Each API key should be limited to a specific number of requests.  If the user is sending to many requests,  then you should prompt them with a captcha (Which could be an error response to a REST request).

**But** in order to enforce this rule then you have to keep server-side state on each client,  and there for this would not be RESTful.   In short,  what you are asking is not simply possible with REST.